# Partial data copy while using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I am using sed to replace occurrences of "Cell\n" in the middle of a line to "Cell".

The script works fine, except that at times the data is not copied fully to the other file.

```
sed ':a
N
$!ba
s/CELL\n/CELL/g
' File1 > File 2
```

In the above code, File 1 has say 100 lines, File 2 has only 20 and in the 20th line (last line) only partial text is being copied.

However on rerunning the same I do not have issues.

Note: I use Datastage to invoke the script.

Comment: Can you post so sample sets of failing files ?

Comment: Sample 1 record form my file1:MR,GAN,KOK TI,,22B5D2,21/02/2014,2,SQ,827,C,SA,22/03/2014,PVG,SIN,HK1,0820 1400,,YYZ1S,AIR,J,1,A,"AC1431524528."," "," ",QJ753698," ","RQST18H"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","144828301664"," "," "," ","SIN  - SINGAPORE AIR","CTCT YYZ416 507 3011 A"," ","CTCB YYZ613 993 0323 B"," ","CTCP YYZ613 410 3257 CELL
PAX"," ",GAN/KOK TIMR,GANKOK TI,28/02/2014,N," ",,CA,,," "," "," "," "

Comment: A couple of things. Is the redirect to `File 2` a typo? Please add sample data to the question, not in the comments, _and_ the sample data should exhibit the problem you have ([SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)).

Comment: Also include in your question the output of `uname` and `sed --version`.If you're using variables for $file1 and $file2, be sure that tney both don't contain the same value. If they do contain same value, you can't use redirection to write back to the same filename and expect to keep all your data. Good luck.

Comment: The problem with partial text at the end of file may be caused be the `N` command which terminates the sed script. Try `$!{N;ba}` also remember the substitution may miss some matches so you will need to issue it twice to catch all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/CELL\n/CELL/;ta;P;D'  file
```